# Convert android.graphics.Path to String And Back to Path

Tags: android, string, path

So I want to convert path to string which is getting saved in `Sharedpreferences` now in next activity I am getting this String but I want to again convert this String to Path. Help me out I have looked on Google but couldn't find anything useful

```
Class A

final Path currentPath = mCurrentPath;
        System.out.println("current path" + currentPath);
        SharedPreferences ap = ctx.getSharedPreferences("lastplayed",
                ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor a = ap.edit();
        a.putString("pattern", currentPath + "");
        a.commit();

Class B

SharedPreferences ap = ctx.getSharedPreferences("lastplayed",
                ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
String path=ap.getString("pattern","0");
```

Now I would like to convert this string object to path again. Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: create custom path that should be seriablizable and send this custom path to next activity through intent.

Comment: can u give some example

Comment: is it working my answer?

Comment: i dont know how to implement it .. well u can do it ? i will b thankfull

Comment: i am not getting you?

Answer (score 0):

You create CustomPath class as follows and send it to the next Activity.

```
public class CustomPath extends Path implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5974912367682897467L;

private ArrayList<PathAction> actions = new ArrayList<CustomPath.PathAction>();

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    in.defaultReadObject();
    drawThisPath();
}

@Override
public void moveTo(float x, float y) {
    actions.add(new ActionMove(x, y));
    super.moveTo(x, y);
}

@Override
public void lineTo(float x, float y){
    actions.add(new ActionLine(x, y));
    super.lineTo(x, y);
}

private void drawThisPath(){
    for(PathAction p : actions){
        if(p.getType().equals(PathActionType.MOVE_TO)){
            super.moveTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
        } else if(p.getType().equals(PathActionType.LINE_TO)){
            super.lineTo(p.getX(), p.getY());
        }
    }
}

public interface PathAction {
    public enum PathActionType {LINE_TO,MOVE_TO};
    public PathActionType getType();
    public float getX();
    public float getY();
}

public class ActionMove implements PathAction, Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7198142191254133295L;

    private float x,y;

    public ActionMove(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public PathActionType getType() {
        return PathActionType.MOVE_TO;
    }

    @Override
    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

}

public class ActionLine implements PathAction, Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8307137961494172589L;

    private float x,y;

    public ActionLine(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public PathActionType getType() {
        return PathActionType.LINE_TO;
    }

    @Override
    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(pathString);
```

Comment: u need to know difference between Path And Uri